# How to do for loop inside a timer tick event vb 2015?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, timer

I would like to do a `For Loop` inside a timer. Since I want to check an array with element `row` continuously and I cant continue since the loop seems to not move from 0 on tick, is there a way around this?

I first tried this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
For row = 0 To 9
msgbox(row)
Next
```

And then I tried another approach, as suggested in an answer

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
row+=1
msgbox(row)
if row = 10 then
timer1.stop()
end if
Next
```

`MsgBox` will now output 0++ on tick but does not stop at 10.

[Output Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6clf.png)

Comment: Yeah, putting a MessageBox in a Tick event is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @LarsTech yes for some reason depending on where the msgbox() is located the output would also change. Like an all 0 output or an unending increment of the row integer. But anyway i think ive solved the problem now ill update the post thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for loop use a global variable and increment it inside the tick function

```
Dim ctr as integer = 0

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

ctr=ctr+1
row(ctr)
msgbox(row)


if ctr == 10 then
ctr = 0
timer1.stop
end if
```

Comment: I agree with this one you dont need to create a loop instead the timer will do the work for you. For every x second then do the code you want

Comment: Just tried out the code above.Unfortunately MsgBox wont stop outputting even after 10 or maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: Still the same output. If I may ask what is the row(ctr) for? I removed it since VB is saying its not a method and so i skipped it and went with msgbox(ctr) directly. Timer1 still doesnt stop though

Comment: Can you show me the output? I think you need to declare ctr as your globals

Comment: ive a added a screenshot above

Comment: Explore more up this answer if it helps you

Comment: @IncogNito Did this fix the issue?

Comment: @David nope just a bit of insight . I think i've solved the issue i'll update the post

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim row As Integer = -1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    RefreshData()
    Timer1.Enabled = True

    initialize()
End sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    increment()
    MsgBox(row)
End sub
Private Sub increment()
    If row > 8 Then
        row = 0

    Else
        row = row + 1

    End If

'my if else statement for checking array variable(row) 
End Sub
```

With this code msgbox was able to output 0 to 9 and repeat the process since i need it to continuously monitor the array. For some reason though when msgbox is situated at the first line of increment method or on timer tick before increment is called the output stays -1 the whole time dunno why. Anyways thanks for all the input as im still new to visual basic 2015